# Vector with known values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

I am new to linear algebra and I am facing this question. Let $A \in \mathbb R^{N \times M}$ be a full rank matrix with $M > N$.
Since $A$ has full rank I can find a solution $\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^M$ of the linear system $A \mathbf x = \mathbf b$ with $\mathbf b \in \mathbb R^N$. However, I want to determine a specific solution $\mathbf x^*$ such that $k$ of its entries with $k < M$ are fixed values.
So here it is my reasoning.
Since I want $\mathbf x^*$ to satisfy $A \mathbf x^* = \mathbf b$, then $\mathbf x^* - \mathbf x \in \mathrm{ker} A$.
Hence, if we have the condition that $\mathrm{dim} \,\mathrm{ker} A > k$, then we can always find a linear span of vectors of a basis of $\mathrm{ker} A$ equal to $\mathbf x^* - \mathbf x$.
My conclusion is that a necessary and sufficient condition to find a solution $\mathbf x^*$ with $k$ known values is that $M - \mathrm{rank}A = M - N = \mathrm{dim}\, \mathrm{ker}A > k$.
Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

It's well known that if a matrix has a kernel there are "free variables" in equations like $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$.  This question might be asking about when you can take *particularly selected* variables to be free.  I say "might be," because it's not clear that the question cares about *which* $k$ values are specified.

To see that it can make a difference, consider $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.  Note that $A \mathbf{x} = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 & x_2 \end{pmatrix}^T$ holds for all $\mathbf{x}$, so that for any $\mathbf{b}$, every solution $\mathbf{x}$ to $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$ has to match $\mathbf{b}$ in the first two components.  So it's possible to arbitrarily specify "one entry" of a solution to $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$, as long as you only want to specify the *third* entry.  For this $A$, you wouldn't be able to arbitrarily specify the first or second entries, no matter what $\mathbf{b}$ is.

If you permute the columns of this example and consider higher dimensional examples, you can see that for any $1 \leq k < M$, there is an $(M-k) \times M$ matrix $A$ having full rank and satisfying $\dim \ker A = k$ with the property for every $\mathbf{b}$, it is possible to arbitrarily specify *one* set of $k$ entries in a solution to $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$, but where it is not possible to arbitrarily specify *any other* choice of $k$ entries in a solution to $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$.

To work on general conditions, let's take $\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{0}$ to start.  For integers $1 \leq n_1 < n_2 < \dots < n_k \leq M$, write $n = (n_1, n_2, \dots, n_k)$, and let $Q_n$ denote the $k \times M$ matrix with $1$s in the row $j$, column $n_j$ entries, $1 \leq j \leq k$, and zeros everywhere else.  Note that for any $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^M$, $Q_n \mathbf{x}$ is the vector $\begin{pmatrix} x_{n_1} & x_{n_2} & \dots & x_{n_k} \end{pmatrix}^T$ obtained from $\mathbf{x}$ by selecting out only the $n_1$th, $n_2$th, ..., $n_k$th entries.  Fix also any $M \times M$ matrix $P$ whose range is $\ker A$.  Then the set $S_n$ of $n_1, n_2, \dots, n_k$th entries of solutions to $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$ is the range of $Q_n P$.

Because $\operatorname{rank}(XY) \leq \operatorname{rank}(Y)$ for any $X$ and $Y$, we deduce that $\dim S_n = \operatorname{rank}(Q_n P) \leq \operatorname{rank}(P) = \dim \ker A$.  Conclusion: if we can arbitrarily specify some selection of $k$ entries in a solution to $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$ (so that $S_n = \mathbf{R}^k$), then $k \leq \dim \ker A$.

Conversely, if $k \leq \dim \ker A$, then $\operatorname{rank}(P) \geq k$.  Because the rank is the dimension of the row space, there is at least one selection of $k$ rows of $P$ - say, the $n_1$th, $n_2$th, ..., $n_k$th rows - that forms a linearly independent list.  Defining $Q_n$ with this tuple $n = (n_1, \dots, n_k)$, we see that $Q_n P$ is just the $k \times M$ matrix consisting of the $n_1$th, ..., $n_k$th rows of $P$, and hence $\operatorname{rank}(Q_n P) = k$.  Because $Q_n P$ is a map from $\mathbb{R}^M$ to $\mathbb{R}^k$ it follows that the range of $Q_n P$ is $\mathbb{R}^k$, i.e., that $S_n = \mathbb{R}^k$.  So we can arbitrarily specify the $n_1$th, ..., $n_k$th entries of a solution to $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$ in this instance.

Summarizing the above, we have:

> Theorem. If if $M > N$ and $A$ is a full rank $N \times M$ matrix and $P$ is a matrix whose range is $\ker A$, then
>
> 1. If $n = (n_1, \dots, n_k)$ is a $k$-tuple of integers satisfying $1 \leq n_1 < \dots < n_k \leq M$, then it is possible to arbitrarily specify the $(n_1, \dots, n_k)$th entries of a solution to $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$ if and only if the $n_1$th, ..., $n_k$th rows of $P$ form a linearly independent list.  In this instance $\dim \ker A \geq k$.
> 2. It is possible to arbitrarily specify *any* choice of $k$ entries of a solution to $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$ if and only if *every* choice of $k$ rows of $P$ forms a linearly independent list.

One possible choice of $P$ is the orthogonal projection onto the nullspace of $A$, which is explicitly given by $A (A^T A)^{-1} A^T$.  If you have a computer program that can tell you the rank of a matrix, you can therefore answer the above question for any given $A$ and choice of $n_1, \dots, n_k$.

I don't know if the condition in 2 above has a simpler characterization.  When $k = 1$, the condition 2 occurs if and only if every row of $P$ is nonzero.  Taking $P$ to be the orthogonal projection onto the nullspace of $A$, we see that this happens if and only if there is a single element of $\ker A$ that fails to be orthogonal to every one of the coordinate axes.  (This does not hold in $2 \times 3$ example $A$ that we started with because every element of $\ker A = \{\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & s\end{pmatrix}^T: s \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is orthogonal to both the first and second coordinate axes, reflecting our inability to freely specify the first and second variables in $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$.)  More generally, the condition appears to encode some kind geometric relation between $\ker A$ and coordinate subspaces.  Maybe someone else will have more information about this condition.

If $\mathbf{b}$ is nonzero things are similar.  We can still consider $P$ as above and run through the argument to see when it's possible to specify the $(n_1, \dots, n_k)$th entries of a solution to $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$ (we need $\dim \ker A \geq k$ and certain rows of $P$ to be linearly independent).  From there, if there's a particular solution $\mathbf{p}$ to $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$, then considering vectors of the form $\mathbf{p} + \mathbf{v}$ where $\mathbf{v}$ is a solution to $A \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{0}$, we see that it's possible to arbitrarily specify the $(n_1, \dots, n_k)$th entries of a solution to $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{v}$ (namely: given a $k$-tuple $(a_1, \dots, a_k)$ that you want, find a solution $\mathbf{v}$ to $A \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{0}$ for which $v_{n_j} = a_j - p_{n_j}$, $1 \leq j \leq k$, and consider $\mathbf{p} + \mathbf{v}$).  And conversely, if we can arbitrarily specify the $(n_1, \dots, n_k)$th entries of a solution to $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{p}$ is a particular solution to $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{p}$, then the vectors $\{\mathbf{v}_j - \mathbf{p}: 1 \leq j \leq k\}$, where $\mathbf{v}_j$ denotes a chosen solution of $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$ with a $1$ in the $n_j$th entry and a zero in the $n_i$th entries for $i \neq j$, will be linearly independent (there are some details to check here) and in $\ker A$, so that $\dim \ker A \geq k$.